# Primay Key conflicts on insertion of new records

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

In a database application, I want to insert, update and delete records in a table of database.
Table is as below:
[image]

In this table, Ga1_ID is Primary Key. 
Suppose, I insert 5 records as show currently.
In second attempt, if I want to insert 5 other records and if any of these new records contains a primary key attribute which is already present in table it show error. Its fine.

But, when I insert new 5 records... how I can verify these new records's primary key value is not present. I mean, how to match or calculate the already present primary key attributes and then insert new records.

What is the best approach to manage this sort of situation ?

Comment: Do you insert new records one by one? if so, you can check if the primary key is duplicate or not, before inserting every single row.

Comment: What is the logic of generating Gal_ID? can't you make it auto increment by database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following query in dataadapter:

```
   da=new SqlDataAdapter("select  Ga1_ID from table where  Ga1_ID=@pkVal",conn);
    DataSet=new DataSet();
    da.fill(ds);

//pass parameter for @pkVal

    da.SelectCommand.Parameters(1).Value = pkValue;    

    if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0) //If number of rows >0 then record exists
     BEGIN
     messagebox.show("Primary key present");
     END
```

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Do not check existing records in advance, i.e. do not SELECT and then INSERT. A better (and pretty common) approach is to try to INSERT and handle exceptions, in particular, catch a primary key violation if any and handle it.

1. Do the insert in a try/catch block, with different handling in case of a primary key violation exception and other sql exception types.
2. If there was no exception, then job's done, record was inserted.
3. If you caught a primary key violation exception, then handle it appropriately (your post does not specify what you want to do in this case, and it's completely up to you)

If you want to perform 5 inserts at once and want to make sure they all succeed or else roll back if any of them failed, then do the inserts within a transaction.

Comment: Exceptional circumstances are best handled with Exception Handling, as suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a lookup first before inserting.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE GA1_id=@newId)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE tableName SET Ga1_docid = @newdocID, GA1_fieldNAme = @newName, Ga1_fieldValue = @newVal where  GA1_id=@newId
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tableName(GA1_ID, Ga1_docid, GA1_fieldNAme Ga1_fieldValue) VALUES (value1,val2,value3,value4)
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would like to have a `surrogate` key wich is generally an `identity` column that will automatically increment when you are inserting rows so that you don't have to care about knowing which `id` already exists.

However, if you have to manually insert the `id` there's a few alternatives for that and knowing wich SQL database you are using would help, but in most SQL implementations, you should be able to do something like:

**IF NOT EXISTS**

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM your_table
        WHERE Ga1_ID = 1
    )
        INSERT INTO ...
```

**SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS**

```
INSERT INTO your_table (col_1, col_2)
SELECT col_1, col_2
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS col_1, 2 AS col_2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 4
) q
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM your_table
    WHERE col_1 = q.col_1
)
```

For **MS SQL Server**, you can also look at the [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb510625.aspx) statement and for **MySQL**, you can use the [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2012, use a sequence object - CREATE SEQUENCE.
This way you can get the next value using NEXT VALUE FOR.

With an older SQL Server version, you need to create the primary key field as an IDENTITY field and use the SCOPE_IDENTITY function to get the last identity value and then increment it manually.